# Intuitively understanding why the charge capacity of a conductive sphere depends on its radius , not its surface area

Tags: electrostatics

I am currently teaching to 9th grades. I tell them: Excess charges are always on the surface of a spherical conductor and I include that the charge capacity of the spherical conductor depends on its radius, not its surface area.

But I get questions from them why it doesn't depends on its surface area if they accumulate on the surface. I wonder what it is best way to explain them without going through some physics formulas.

Comment: Since for a spherical conductor, the surface area depends upon the radius, the two are not unrelated. For more general surfaces, I like to think of it in terms of the charge capacity at a point as being related to the curvature of the surface.

Answer (score 2):

Capacity is defined as quotient of charge $Q$ and electric potential $\phi$. Since the electric potential scales as $\frac{1}{r}$, the capacity turns out to be proportional to $r$ and not to $r^2$.

$C=\frac{Q}{\phi}$ and $\phi = \frac{Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 r}$ yields
$$C=4\pi\varepsilon_0 r$$

I think, that it is very difficult to boil this down to a student that has no intuition for the concept of the electric potential $\phi$ and the concept of capacity $C$.

As far as I understand it, there are three key ideas that you need to understand, before you can build intuition.

1.) The surface charge density is related to the electric field strength: $\frac{Q}{A}=\varepsilon_0 E$, and

2.) And the electric field strength can be derived from the electric potential: $E = -\frac{d\phi}{dr}$

3.) The capacity of an object measures its capability of storing charge depending on the provided amount of "energy" $C=\frac{Q}{\phi}$

From there, you can understand the capacity of an ordinary capacitor with surface area $A$ and plate separation $d$
$$\frac{Q}{A}=\varepsilon_0 E = \varepsilon_0 \frac{\phi}{d} \Longrightarrow C=\frac{Q}{\phi}=\varepsilon_0\frac{A}{d}$$

Here you actually find the dependence on the surface area $A$. However, the plate separation $d$ also appears in the denominator. So that effectively again, the capacity scales like length and not like a surface.

There is one more thought: The total strength electric field outside a charged sphere solely depends on the amount of charge that's contained. It does not depend on the particular distribution of the charge. And as far as the energy of the storage is concered this only depends on the radial coordinate (analogy to the height in the gravitational field might be useful).

Comment: 9th graders are not knowing either electric potential (10th graders ok.) or capacity( 12th graders ok. too)